# Algorithm of $n = x^2 y$ to simplify a squrae root of n

Tags: number-theory

we can simplify a square root $$\sqrt 8 = \sqrt {2^2 \cdot 2} = 2\sqrt 2$$
I need a good algorithm to simplify a big integer $n$ of thousands digits.
$$\text{for constant } n \in \mathbb N \\x, y \in \mathbb N \\ \text{ } \\ \text{find positive integer solution }(x,y) \text{ in}\\ n = x^2 y$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you want $y$ to be square free? Otherwise $x=1, y=n$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that there is a good algorithm because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Square-free_factorization) says

> every known algorithm for computing a square-free factorization [of  integer] computes also the prime factorization.